# How do I send Meta Messages that has more than 3 bytes data with Pygame.midi?

Tags: python, pygame, midi

I'm trying to send Meta Messages has more than 3 bytes data.
But an error is appeared.

> Too many data bytes (8) in event no. 0.

It's because pygame.midi write method can send data till 3 bytes.

Is it impossible?

i use python 2.7, pygame 1.9.4 and OSX 10.13.6(High Sierra)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source file](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/0f628ff4a2b45b2c4c35b6b3c5e67c8103f8788d/src_c/pypm.pyx#L407), the length of your message string exceeds the maximum allowed length of **4** (8>4)

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I know the maximum length is 3 bytes data.
But my midi meta message has 8 bytes.

Comment: @daisuke edit the pygame source to accept more than 3 and re-build

Answer (score 0):

`Write` is used only for channel messages.

To output SysEx messages, use `WriteSysEx`:

```
out.WriteSysEx(0, '\\xF0\\x7D\\x10\\x11\\x12\\x13\\xF7')
out.WriteSysEx(0, [0xF0, 0x7D, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0xF7])
```

Meta messages are not MIDI messages, and are never sent over MIDI. Your program itself has to handle them.

Comment: I want to send Meta message signal. like this.
time_stamp = 0, data = [255, 88, 4, 4, 4, 18,8]

I think that in write_sys_ex function,  the first of the data list must be 240, the last must be 247.
I trid to send above data, but below error is occured.

>Exception: PortMidi: `Invalid MIDI message Data'

Comment: The time signature affects how your own program displays notes, but not how the messages are played, or the receiving MIDI device.

Comment: "Need" is irrelevant; you *cannot* send them.